# AVD não carrega

Tags: android, android-eclipse, avd

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uso o android a um tempinho e depois que formatei meu note e instalei o eclipse/android o emulador simplesmente não funciona. Ele não carrega, só fica lá parado, mas não dá erro nem nada. O que poderia ser?

Comment: Poderia mandar um print da tela que fica?

Comment: adicionei um print

Comment: Apesar de não resolver o problema, recomendo dar uma olhada no Genymotion. Muita gente abandonou as AVD's e começou a usar o Genymotion. Ele cria uma camada em cima da VirtualBox, com diversas configurações de versões de Android e dispositivo. É bem mais rapido que as AVD's.

Answer (score 1):

Olá!

Infelizmente o AVD é muito lento. Na minha opinião a melhor alternativa é utilizar o GenyMotion pois com ele você simplesmente escolhe um aparelho, baixa a .iso e depois da play. Funciona muito mais rápido do que um AVD da vida.

Link para download do GenyMotion: https://www.genymotion.com/?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter#!/

Passo a passo da instalação: http://www.techtudo.com.br/dicas-e-tutoriais/noticia/2013/12/veja-como-emular-o-android-no-computador-com-o-genymotion.html

Answer (score 0):

Pensei em duas coisas, primeiro o emulador é pesando, dependendo da máquina pode demorar de iniciar, e outra a criação e configuração correta do emulador, display, processador, memoria(sempre levando em conta a memoria atual disponível em sua máquina, que possa trabalhar bem), verifique novamente a configuração, assim como a variável path do android, necessária para o emulador unidade onde o emulador esta etc.

Outro caminho é usar o Android Studio, uma IDE dedicada ao android que contem emulador integrado e funcional, caso não funcione verifique as configurações da sua máquina para ver se a máquina é capaz de iniciar em tempo hábil um emulador, e também configurações dele.

Android Studio: [http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html]

Comment: Obrigada.. Mas a maquina aguenta sim a emulação, sempre trabalhei nela. Já fiz varias verificações, emulações com varias versões diferentes e nada.

Comment: Certo, de nada o Android Studio é uma boa !

Answer (score 0):

Tente instalar o [Intel HAXM](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager). No computador em que utilizo, ele ajudou e muito a acelerar o boot e a utilização do Android emulado no computador. Lembrando que, para ter esse ganho de performance, é necessário também baixar a imagem da Intel (pelo SDK Manager é possível) para ter uma melhora perceptível.

Ou como o nosso colega Wakim disse, o [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter#!/) é uma ótima opção também.